# Tool or procedure to check Firebird 1.5 schema against Firebird 2.5 requirements

Tags: database, firebird

Is there a tool or written procedure to check what needs to be fixed in a Firebird 1.5 scnema to make it useable in a Firebird 2.5 environment.

I know there were changes and reserved words added in 2.0 but some of that seems to have been lessoned or changed again in 2.5.

Is simply trying to load the schema in 2.5 enough? Will the triggers be validated upon creation or only when they actually run?

Is there a definitive list of changes somewhere that I can't seem to find?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply get your code into a sql script and try to execute it against an empty Firebird 2.5 database and check for any failures. Doing this way, all the database objects will be created and any incompatibility will result in errors.

Note that backup and restore will not validate already existing triggers and procedures against new reserved words, etc. If you hit any of them, you would know only when you try to recompile the trigger/procedure, so creating a fresh database and applying the script is the easiest way to be 100% guaranteed.

Comment: Thank you. I was not certain when the triggers would be double checked.